N_CR and N_AS Timeout in LIN communication
I am new to LIN protocol so far understood LIN communication and implemented the stack which is working fine for me now I want to implement N_CR and N_AS timeout.
I want to know where this timeout is implemented in what condition.
the timeout is 1000ms.
From my CAPL the master request (3C) and next request time is 50ms.
I am using timer2 with 1000ms.
when I use TIMER_Enable(TIM2) in main function and sending multiple MasterReq from CAPL
the debug hits here in the middle of transmission.
void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
if(timeout_type == N_CR_TIMEOUT)
{
timout_type = N_CR_ERROR;
}

So where should I enable the timer here whether in after receiving the FirstFrame and next consecutive frame.
